# Perform initial task with parameters before executing function in JS

Tags: javascript, function, class, object, ecmascript-6

I'm making a tool. This tool should be able to accept parameter, perform an initial task to the parameters, then return a result depending on which function is invoked.

My first attempt was using an object. But I had to repeat the initial task on each function

```js
const test1 = {
  add: (a, b) => {
    a = a + 1; // This part became repetitive
    b = b + 1; // and I had to copy it to other function
    return a + b;
  },
  multiply: (a, b) => {
    a = a + 1;
    b = b + 1;
    return a * b;
  }
}
console.log("test1=" + test1.add(1, 2));
```

Then I tried with a function and using switch case instead. This is currently what I'm using for this problem. Is this the best solution for this?

```js
function test2(o, a, b) {
  a = a + 1;
  b = b + 1;
  switch (o) {
    case "add":
      return (a + b);
    case "multiply":
      return (a * b);
  }
}
console.log("test2=" + test2("add", 1, 2));
```

But then I thought of using classes. I call it by creating new class object and call the class's function

```js
class test3 {
  constructor(a, b) {
    this.a = a + 1;
    this.b = b + 1;
  }
  add() {
    return this.a + this.b;
  }
  multiply() {
    return this.a * this.b;
  }
}
console.log("test3=" + new test3(1, 2).add());
```

This seems much neater and easier to read than switch case, but I'm worried that I'm creating a new class over and over for a function I'll use once but then discard.

Is there a way to keep make the class perform the initial task with the parameter but keep the functions static so I don't have to instantiate a **new** class object everytime I need to use it?

I feel like I am missing something. Is there a better way to tackle this?

Comment: Why don't you just pass parameter to your functions in your class directly? then you may call it like this: `test3.add(1,2)`. which I think is more readable and also you've got rid of `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the module pattern like this:

```js
function test1(a, b) {
  const _a = a + 1;
  const _b = b + 1;  
  function addNums() {    
    return _a + _b;
  }
  function multiplyNums() {    
    return _a * _b;
  }
  return {
    add: addNums,
    multiply: multiplyNums
  }  
}

const api = test1(1,2);
console.log(api.add());
console.log(api.multiply());
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add when you're doing the maths?

```js
 

const test1 = {
  add: (a, b) => ++a + ++b,
  multiply: (a, b) => ++a * ++b
}
console.log(test1.add(1, 2));
console.log(test1.multiply(1, 2));
```